# WinForms/C#: Adding items to Combox and controlling the Item value (numeric)

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, combobox

I have been populating my Items to a combox using the designer and all i pass is a string.

Although now i need to control which key/index is stored with each item.

I thought there was a item object, but i looked at the method ADD and it accepts object..

How do i pass in an control the key/index i.e. what is returned when i do SelectedItem.

So if i do selectedtext i get back a string that is displayed in the current selected dropdown but if i do selecteditem i want to get back a custom number that i need to store with it...

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks in  advance

Comment: You can you `Dictionary` as show here http://madprops.org/blog/Bind-a-ComboBox-to-a-generic-Dictionary

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get Value from ComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850946/cant-get-value-from-combobox)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind it to a collection of key\value objects and use the [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) and [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) properties to set what is displayed/returned.

Heres an example:

```
public class ComboItem
{
    public string stringValue { get; set; }
    public int indexValue { get; set; }
}

public void LoadCombo()
{
     List<ComboItem> list = new List<ComboItem>();
     // populate list...
     // then bind list
     myComboBox.DisplayMember = "stringValue";
     myComboBox.ValueMember = "indexValue";
     myComboBox.DataSource = list;
}
```

Then

```
myComboBox.SelectedText       // will return stringValue
myComboBox.SelectedValue      // will return indexValue
myComboBox.SelectedItem       // will return the ComboItem itself
myComboBox.SelectedIndex      // will return the items index in the list
```

Alternatively you could store the index by adding a [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property (which is often used to store things like this) by creating a custom combo item, [have a read here for how to do this](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=320924)