# C# ComboBox String value to object variable to class?

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to take a string value from a Combo box then pass it through an object variable to a class and store it there in a string variable.

```
 private void cboTimeZone_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     extTime1.timeZone = cboTimeZone.SelectedItem;
 }
```

I'm not totally use to the combo box options to use so.

Comment: _"Passing a string value from a ComboBox through an object variable to a class into a string variable"_ -- What exactly do you mean by thet? Does it mean that you want to store the current text value of a ComboBox in another object's `string` field/property? Then it's a simple assignment.

Comment: >> My poor explanation in that content is poor. 
I want to store the current text value of the ComboBox selectedValue in a string variable in a class. extTime1 is an object variable of that class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get Value from ComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850946/cant-get-value-from-combobox)

Comment: *@allthosemiles:* The following explanation about terminology is somewhat off-topic here, but still valuable to know: In C#, you usually don't call an class' **fields** and **properties** "variables"; same as you wouldn't call **methods** "functions" or "procedures". (So, if you say "string variable in a class", some people like me would probably reach the conclusion that you meant a static field of type `string` in some unnamed class, which is not what you apparently mean.)

Comment: Okay. thank you. ^_^ Still getting use to this. And all of the terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the cboTimeZone contain string objects? In this case, a simple cast should be enough if extTime1.timeZone is a string:

```
extTime1.timeZone = (string)cboTimeZone.SelectedItem
```

if cboTimeZone was filled with objects of type `myObject`, u can use the ToString() method on the item if you overwrote it in your `myObject` class:

```
extTime1.timeZone = cboTimeZone.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

If you selected a specific property `MyProperty` of `myObject` to be shown in the combo box, you can first cast to the object and then access the property by using

```
extTime1.timeZone = ((myObject)cboTimeZone.SelectedItem).MyProperty
```

to get that property as a result.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I've never seen a placement of (string) like that. That was what i needed.

Comment: Since everything derives from Object and ToString is a member of Object, there is no need for the additional cast in the second example.

Comment: +1 yeah, you are right, thanks for the hint. It only may be interesting to cast to the object if you want to link to a certain property. I will change that above.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether your `ComboBox` is data-bound or not; either way, I think it would be a good idea to first figure out if `SelectedItem` is indeed the correct property to use, or if there's another, more appropriate one.

If you've set a `DataSource` for your `ComboBox`, you've probably also set a `DisplayMember`. In that case, the `DisplayMember` will determine which property of the currently selected item of the data source will be shown in the `ComboBox` as text.

If you've set a `ValueMember`, you can also use the **`SelectedValue`** property to retrieve that property of the currently selected data source item.

**`SelectedItem`** simply retrieves the currently selected data source item. This may be a complex object, or a string object, or something else; check with your data source.

The `ComboBox`'s **`Text`** property simply contains the text that's currently displayed in the `ComboBox`'s text input field and has type `string`.