# how can i set properties to serial port from a combobox?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

HI!

I made a code for a windows application to communicate via serial port. I want to set the parameters manually by using some combo boxes in my windows form that contain the possible values of baud rate, parity bit etc. I made a bit of a code that gives me in a text box the names of the com ports available and i can select them but i need to set serial port parameters that i set in the combo boxes by pressing a button. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the ComPort class? I believe you specify the COM port, baud etc when creating the instance of the ComPort class - so you'd need to close, re-create and re-open the object each time you want to apply changes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get Value from ComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850946/cant-get-value-from-combobox)

Comment: Can you show some code like where you append port names in textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to change the serial port parameters before or after you created your serial port object?

I have a project that interacts with an Arduino using the USB interface.  Here is my code to create a SerialPort:

```
string comPort = cboComPorts.SelectedItem.ToString();
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(comPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
```

As you can see the comPort is selected from a dropdown.  When my program starts up, it lists all the available COM ports in that dropdown.  Then, as you can see, I use it as a first parameter when creating my SerialPort object.  Then it takes an int for the baud rate and a couple of other parameters.  If you want to be able to enter these on a form and use them to instantiate the SerialPort it's not a huge deal you just have to write out some code to capture the information you need just like I have done with the first parameter here.

If you provide some of the code that you already so we can see what you're trying to do exactly, we might be able to give you a better answer.